# ERROR: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output (no FTP access)

Tags: login, errors

I am trying to log in the WordPress of a deceased friend to remove his page, but I get the error message described in the title when trying to do so. I saw many messages advising to modify some files via FTP, but I do not have such access. What can I do?

Comment: is this hosted on wordpress.com? This is usually caused by code that generates php notices/warnings, and the fix is to disable the plugin responsible or fix the warnings/notices, but if you do not have FTP access then that will be difficult if not impossible. You may require help from the hosting company that hosts the site, and you'll need to persuade them that your friend is indeed deceased, but also that you are responsible for managing their affairs to gain control of their account, assuming the host has such a process. The host may be able to turn off displaying notices/warnings

Comment: Yes I think it is hosted on Wordpress. At least I could find only Wordpress emails in his mailbox about this website. From what I understood it seems that FTP access has to be enabled for me to be able to connect. I tried to access it with Filezilla but it could not connect to ftp://myfriendpage so I suppose it is not enabled right?

Comment: Can it be that my friend created a Wordpress without having a Wordpress account? We could not find any credentials, and his email seems to not be related to any account. It seems that if I want to get support from Wordpress I need to create an account myself.

Comment: if it's hosted on wordpress.com then you need to contact their support, it's highly unlikely anybody here or elsewhere can help without their involvement. Only WordPress.com support can answer that. This stack is for programmers working with the open source WordPress software